# Unicorn Refreshing Gem List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

Guys I'm trying to restart my unicorn service and seems it get stuck on this

> [2019-03-06T20:45:05.938802 #7614]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
>
> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@citius_artis/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:49:in
>
> `block in builder': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)
> (ArgumentError)

Did not change anything on gemfile

If I run rails s -e staging the rails starts normally

Any ideas?

My unicorn.rb config

```
APP_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__)))

# puts "APP ROOT ->>> #{APP_ROOT}"

if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    # puts "RUBY HOME ->>> #{rvm_path}"
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    # $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    # require 'rvm'
    # RVM.use_from_path! APP_ROOT
  rescue LoadError
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'

if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  worker_processes 2
else
  worker_processes 2
end

working_directory APP_ROOT

preload_app true

timeout 60

listen APP_ROOT + "/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

pid APP_ROOT + "/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path APP_ROOT + "/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path APP_ROOT + "/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # puts "SERVER ->>> #{server}"

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) && ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  old_pid = APP_ROOT + '/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin'
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # puts "Old master alerady dead"
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] || Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Comment: try downgrading to 5.4

Comment: Could you upload your unicorn config code?

Comment: updated it @HDox

Comment: updated @FailingCoder

Comment: Is it a bug in the updated unicorns or was something deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem and following John Smith's advice this worked for me:

```
bundle exec gem list | grep unicorn # returns unicorn (5.5.0)
```

change Gemfile to gem 'unicorn', '5.4.1'

```
bundle install

bundle exec gem list | grep unicorn # returns unicorn (5.4.1)
```

Then I was able to restart unicorn without error

Comment: Yes!! The problem for me was definitively the gemset, I removed the gemset and added again it works for me.

Comment: You no longer need to downgrade. The newest version (5.5.1) fixes this issue, simply upgrade now.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there was a bug introduced in 5.5.0
https://bogomips.org/unicorn-public/20190307022859.mxz7m3mbspujo4c2@dcvr/

I tested his patched version and it works:

Set unicorn version in Gemfile

```
gem "unicorn", "~> 5.5.0.1.g6836"
```

And ran `bundle update unicorn`